# Android Switch method dont work

Tags: android

When I change the swith to on or off, I want call that method checkswitch.

I have the code:

```
int swflag=0;
public void checkswitch(View view)
{
    Switch sw =(Switch)findViewById(R.id.switch1);

    if(sw.isChecked())
        swflag=1;
    else
        swflag=0;
}
```

But this doen't work because the flag doesn't change, it probably is because I'm using OnClick in xml. I'm using android studio.

Somebody can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Please explain **completely and precisely** what "dont work dont know why?" means.

Comment: Which sdk are you using? please post catLog if you have and post xml plus more code

Comment: `I have that code:` No, you have `more` than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.example.testing;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Switch;
public class SwitchTesting extends Activity
{
    int swflag=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.switch_widget_sample);

        Switch swichObj = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        swichObj.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    swflag = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    swflag = 0;
                }
                Log.d("swflag Value  = ", Integer.toString(swflag));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It works for me. Switch Widget will be Avaliable on API Level 14 and Above

Comment: Ok, thanks for the code, works 100%, and thanks to all who try help me. And the code: ´// TODO Auto-generated method stub´ its just a comment? becouse the color is blue

Comment: thanks Rushabh Patel for Code Formatting. Sorry to remove TODO Comment.if the code works means Vote for it.

Comment: Y, i forgot to vote sorry.

Answer (score 0):

i did this for Toggle button..
if you have

```
tgl_switch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(tgl_switch.isChecked()){

               // Your Code Here 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Switch ON",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{


                 // else part
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Switch off",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }});
```

Comment: Dont have but thanks anyway.